# c# Azure Management Lib Get list of only web roles

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

My environment contains a both web roles and classic vm. Using Azure Management Lib how do i get the list of only the web roles. I tried but this lists both classic vm and web roles. I could not find any property to filter out web role.

```
ComputeManagementClient computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(tokenCred);
HostedServiceListResponse cloudServices = computeClient.HostedServices.List();
```

Is there a way through program to find out if it is a web role or a classic vm

Answer (score 0):

A cloud service is simply a container that can host both Web/Worker roles and Virtual Machines. Listing the cloud services using the code above will not tell you if it is containing a Web/Worker role or a VM.

What you would need to do is get deployment details of each cloud service and find out the Role type. For VMs, this value would be `PersistentVMRole`. If you find a deployment where the role type value is not this, that would mean it is a Web/Worker role.